# Algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ including all the roots of $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, extension-field

In general if I "add" to the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ the square root of two, the extension will be algebraic and of the form:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\dfrac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{(X^2-2)}=\left\{ q_0 +q_1\sqrt{2} \ \bigg| q_0,q_1 \in \mathbb{Q} \right\}$

The same kind of construction for the cubic root of two will yield the following extension:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})=\dfrac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{(X^3-2)}=\left\{ q_0 +q_1\sqrt[3]{2} + q_2(\sqrt[3]{2})^2 \ \bigg| q_0,q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb{Q} \right\}$

We easily see that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \nsubseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}) \supseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Now, if I want to describe $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{2})$ I can proceed in this way:

$12=3 \times 4= 3 \times 2^2$

This implies that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[4]{2})$

---

**Now**, with these examples in mind, I want to build, if it has a sense, the infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, adding all the $n$-roots of $2$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[5]{2},...,\sqrt[n]{2},...) $

I can describe this extension using only prime numbers and their power:

$\large \mathbb{Q}(\left\{ \sqrt[p^{\alpha}]{2} \right\}_{p \ \text{over} \ \textit{primes},\\ \alpha \in \mathbb{N}}  )$

But actually I don't know if this is helpful.

Is there a way to give sense at this extensions?

P.s. I was also thinking about direct limits, and describe this extension as a direct limit of finite $n$**th**-extensions of the form $\left\{ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[5]{2},...,\sqrt[n]{2}) \right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. But here i don't know properties of closure to direct limits of the category of fields $\mathcal{Fld}$

Comment: You can definitely write it as the inverse limit of those embeddings in the category of fields. Whether this gives sense to anything, it's up to your sense of humor. $\ddot\smile$ It provides an explicit set-theoretic construction, though.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It's a direct limit, not an inverse limit.

Comment: It's a direct limit, but a colimit. Inverse limit corresponds to limit. It's not even slightly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a union of the chain of subfields

$$Q\left(2^{1/n!}\right), \;n = 1,2,3, ...$$

of the field of algebraic numbers.